# Redirect all HTTP urls to HTTPS for frontend in magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, magento-1.9.1

I want to redirect all `http` urls to `https` in magento, but for front-endonly. In magento we have a setting to use secure urls for front-end as explained in this link: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm but that applies to only pages shown after login or checkout.

I have applied following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

It is working ok, but it is redirecting Admin panel urls to `https` as well. I don't want that, I want only front-end to secure not the admin panel urls.

Please check and advise if we can do such thing in magento?

Comment: keep in mind server port is default 80 can be 8080 81 82 or what ever... next point, why don't you want security for ADMIN-PANEL?

Comment: I don't want HTTPS for admin panel, because it is creating issue when I try to save data, sometimes data not saved properly. So, I want it not to apply on admin urls.

Comment: @Prashant Probably because you are redirecting post requests

Answer (score 3):

First remove your rule.

Then, as per [this reference](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm) go to your admin area. Go to System > Configuration > Web > Secure and turn on the options "Use secure URLS in frontend" and "Use secure URLS in admin".

Links on your website should now all be https. You can use the following rule to redirect people that bookmarked the http-version of your site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Change the `R` flag to `R=301` after testing everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) recommend against using a rewrite:

> To redirect `http` URLs to `https`, do the following:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     Redirect / https://www.example.com/
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     # ... SSL configuration goes here
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

This snippet should go into main server configuration file, **not** into `.htaccess` as asked in the question.

This article might have come up only after the question was asked and answered, but seems to be the current way to go.

Comment: Where is this configuration file?

Comment: it depends on Opereating system. In Ubuntu you can find the configuration file in folder "/etc/apache2/sites-available"