# Index.php in all Urls and HTTPS Redirect Issue

Tags: magento, redirect, https

1st Issue : In Every Urls Keep index.php.I want to Remove Index.php from every Url

2nd Issue : I have Installed SSL . So Site Working file in Https Version . But If anyone Reach a Urls without HTTPS version like http://www.test.com/contact.php it should Redirect to https://www.test.com/contact.php But it's Redirecting to Home Page

Wish will Get Solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all HTTP urls to HTTPS for frontend in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167858/redirect-all-http-urls-to-https-for-frontend-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

To remove `index.php` from all pages,refer the below link.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938860/how-do-i-remove-index-php-from-the-url-in-magento)